# How to remove vertical line in RStudio editor?

Tags: r, rstudio

[image: here you can see some weird line i dont know how to get rid of it, changing the appearance doesn't work]
Here you can see some weird line i dont know how to get rid of it, changing the appearance doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set this in Tools / Global Options / Code / Display / Show margin
[image]